# laravel POST method not allowed

Tags: laravel

am using laravel with ajax to get a report for staff, my view code

```
 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">
 <form id="form_startTimeReport" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
  <input type="hidden" value="xxx" name="xxx" id="xxx">
  <div class="form-row">
   <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
    <button type="submit" id="form_startTimeReport_button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm radius mt-2 shadow">{{ __('messages.Search')}}</button>                                            </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

and in my route file

```
Route::post('/startTime-report', 'StaffController@startTimeReport')->name('startTimeReport');
```

in javaScript file

```
    $('button#form_startTimeReport_button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span> Loading...');
        var formData = new FormData($('#form_startTimeReport')[0]);
        alert(formData.get('xxx'));
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: config.routes.startTimeReport,
                type: "POST",
                enctype: "multipart/form-data",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    //alert(result);
                    var myWindow = window.open(config.routes.startTimePopup, '_blank', 'top=0,left=500,width=1200,height=250,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
                    myWindow.document.write(result.html);
                    $(this).html(config.messages.searchReport);
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert(request.statusText + "[" + request.status + "]");
                    alert(request.responseText);
                    $(this).html(config.messages.searchReport);
                }
            });
        }, AjaxTimeBeforeCalling);
    });
```

and in my controller file

```
    public function startTimeReport(Request $request)
    {
        $staffs = Stafftime::select(
            'id',
            'starttime',
            'endtime',
            'states',
            'staff_id',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at'
        )->where('states', '=', 'open')
            ->get();

        //return $staffs;
        $view = view('admin.staff.reports.startTimeReport', compact('staffs'))->render();
        return response()->json(['html' => $view]);
    }
```

i have an error (method not allowed[405]) the POST method is not supported for this route.Supported method GET,HEAD

Comment: make sure that `config.routes.startTimeReport` is a right route.

Comment: Please make sure that config.routes.startTimeReport is taken from the same route name: route('startTimeReport'). Usually this mistake happens.

Comment: IT'S the right route, am sure, if the type of ajax is get its work done, but i want the post method

Comment: are you making sure the javascript is even running? as your form action is the current URL because it is empty and that is most likely a GET route returning that form

Answer (score 1):

you can test two things
first add csrf to ajax request

```
headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
```

or

```
    data: {
    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    "id": id
    }
```

and second remove route cache

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: I have a headers CSRF Token already, and i clear the route cache, same problem (method not allowed[405])

Comment: first where is it  csrf token in ajax exactly ?

Comment: $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
        }
    });

Comment: where do you get config.routes.startTimeReport, value in ajax?

Comment: in app.blade.php i create an object config like startTimeReport    : "{{ route('startTimeReport') }}",

Comment: may i see that part of file

Comment: i have around 50 route in my object and it's work done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240070/discussion-between-mahdi-darvishiyan-and-ahmad-almasri).